# Service being disabled after package updates

Tags: apt, services

We use the stork service specifically for monitoring our Kea server installations.  This is running on Ubuntu 22.  I use systemctl to enable the service for auto start.  Every time I patch these systems and there's an update to stork (either agent or server), the service gets disabled.  I have to manually use systemctl again to enable and start the service.  Is there any way I can configure apt/etc to make sure these services stay enabled after running apt upgrade?

It's crazy to me that if I have a service set as enabled, that an upgrade process would disable it, but it happens on all 5 servers I have stork installed on.